# Java 8 streams to find number of factors

Tags: java, java-8, runtime-error

I am stuck in the below problem to find the number of factors of a given number using Java 8 -streams.While submitting the solution in codechef , one of the subtasks got accepted but all others threw a NZEC and the solution was not accepted.
I tried wrapping the code in the try/catch block but i still get NZEC as the output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCases = scanner.nextInt();
        while (--testCases >= 0) {
            int nValue = scanner.nextInt();
            int product = 1;
            while (nValue-- != 0) {
                int currentVal = scanner.nextInt();
                product *= currentVal;
            }
            int prod = product;
            System.out.println(Stream.iterate(2, x -> x + 1).limit(prod / 2).filter(num -> prod % num == 0).count() + 2);
        }
    }
}
```

I am really new to competitive coding and unable to figure out the issue with the above code.Please help....

Comment: I think you better talk about it here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Some things that might cause problems:

- Using `int` for `product` might overflow (exceeding `Integer.MAX_VALUE`), especially with multiplying. This might result in a negative value for `product` giving you `IllegalArgumentException` for a negative `limit()`. You should switch to `long`
- Limit should be `Math.ceil(sqrt(product))`
- You should not multiply at, it is much faster to calculate the factors for the separate `currentValue` and join the result.